# a challenge dealing with `array_value_exists` function

Tags: php, arrays

Take a look at this array as an example please.

`$my_array = array('jan','feb','march','april');`

Here, I'd like to check if the string `'arc'` exists as part of my array values... 
( even it were to exist partially as in the string `march`), I'd like the function to return TRUE. I would also ignore the case. So `'ARC'` too should return TRUE.

I thought about using `array_value_exists` here but it's got two issues going against me;  1) it is  case sensitive. 
2) & it looks for an exact match.

what's the best way to handle this situation?

So, should I set up a `foreach` loop and then go for a `strpos` checks? 
or should I convert the array into a serialized form and perhaps also deploy reg_exp?

What would be your take on this?

Has anyone written a function like this?

P.S.
As to the multidimensional array situation, it is OK for it to traverse all values..

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following, which uses [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator) and [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos):

```
function array_subvalue_recursive($arr, $value) {
    $itr = new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr);
    foreach ($itr as $current)
        if (is_string($current) && stripos($current, $value) !== false)
            return $current;
    return null;
}
```

```
array_subvalue_recursive($my_array, 'arc'); // returns "march"
```

Or if you do not require recursive searching of the array:

```
function array_subvalue_recursive($arr, $value) {
    foreach ($arr as $current)
        if (is_string($current) && stripos($current, $value) !== false)
            return $current;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works (is case insensitive as well)

```
preg_grep( "/arc/i" , $my_array );
```

$my_array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => jan
  [1] => feb
  [2] => march
  [3] => april
)
```

Result:

```
Array
(
 [2] => march
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of flat arrays, where all values are always strings, you can use something like this:

```
$newArray = array_filter($my_array, function($value) { return stripos($value, 'arc') !== false; })
```

`$newArray` will then hold all matched values, in this example `march`.

(As soon as there is any non-string value in the array, stripos will trigger wanrings.)

Comment: this is one of those situations where all answers are awesome.